# Can Java Jersey inject HeaderParam and FormParam into class private variables?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I wrote the following code:

> public class UserAccountWebServices {
>
> ```
> @Context
> protected HttpHeaders httpHeaders;
>
> @HeaderParam("Authorization")
> private String authorization;
>
> @FormParam("UserAccountIdentifier")
> private String userAccountIdentifier;
> ```
>
> ...

The thing is that my class variables (authorization and userAccountIdentifier) are marked "private" and IntelliJ IDEA flags a warning - saying that they were never assigned. I still have a long way to go before compiling and running it, so I would appreciate if someone could tell me if it would work - injected into a private variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that works (assuming you are using Jersey).